# Prove that for every nonempty set $A$, there is a a one-to-one function from $A$ to $A \times A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am very confused how this works. How can I prove that an unnamed set be injective with a cartesian set comprised of the same set?

Along with the above question, how can I prove the opposite? That $A \times A \to A$ is injective?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you choose $a_0 \in A$, then you get a injection by $a \mapsto (a,a_0)$. Is this what you want ?

Comment: sorry i am unclear with general mathematical terms. What does "a naught" mean?

Comment: $a_0$ is just some, arbitrary element of $A$. Changing it will change the one-to-one function you get, but no matter what you choose it to be, the result is one-to-one. However, making it the "diagonal" map $(a, a)$, as in Kavi's answer, works just as well. P.S, if you wish to write $a_0$, type `$a_0$`.

Comment: okay thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(a)=(a,a)$ is an injective map from $A$ to $A \times A$. Converse is false. If $A=\{0,1\}$ then there is no injective map from $A \times A$ to $A$.